# Question that popped out due to this OMO problem

Tags: systems-of-equations

I had laid my hand on an OMO (Online Math Open) problem which was

> Convex pentagon $ABCDE$ is inscribed in circle $\gamma$. Suppose that $AB=14$, $BE=10$, $BC=CD=DE$, and $[ABCDE]=3[ACD]$. Then there are two possible values for the radius of $\gamma$. The sum of these two values is $\sqrt{n}$ for some positive integer $n$. Compute $n$

By using my Geometry Theorems (Ptolemy, Fact 5,etc) the following system of equations came up (after labelling some lengths as $a,b,c,d,x$)-

> $$14a+bc=2ab$$ $$14x+bx=ad$$ $$xc+14d=10a$$ $$cd+14x=10b$$ $$xc+ax=d$$

There are five equations, and five variables, but are quite clumsily presented and do not look like how simple equations should look like, and we didn't find a solution to this till now, even after lot of algebraic manipulations. I suspect it cannot be solved *only* using these, perhaps we need more constraints. But can in general, equations like this (coefficients consist of variables) having # of variables$=$ # of equations have solutions which can be found out.

It would be great if this could be solved with Linear Algebra.

EDIT: I am interested in the methods to solve system of equations such as this, not the problem, the problem was mentioned just as an example to show such a system if equations.

Comment: What does $[ABCDE]=3[ACD]$ mean?

Comment: It means area of the pentagon $ABCDE=3$ times the area of $\Delta ACD$ but i only stated the problem to give an example of such a system of equations

Comment: System like this are not linear, so techniques other than linear algebra are needed to solve them, if indeed, they can be solved.

Comment: Any such general way?

Comment: Not to my knowledge, but I'm no algebraist.  I'm guessing this is a contest problem, right?  Then there must be a way that doesn't depend on really advanced techniques.   I imagine that there are other applicable geometric facts you haven't used.

Comment: I know a solution not involving systems of equations, but i am emphasizing on the method of solving the system rather than on solving the problem.